# Игра ожидает окончания выполнения DLL, хотя они должны выполняться одновременно

Tags: c++, dll

Ну, думаю вы уже прочитали тему, так что сразу перечислю мои неудачные попытки решить это и код.
Попытка первая - получить доступ к памяти игры, найти значение GameState, проверить, равно ли оно шести(свободная езда в nfs:mw), если да то выполняю основной код игры. Парадокс в том, что пока gamestate не равен 6, dll не продолжит работу, а пока dll не продолжит работу, GameState не будет равно 6. И так в принципе до бесконечности.
Попытка два: выкинуть DLL в отдельный поток. Я думал это точно работает, но тоже самое. Вот только на этот раз я не смог найти источник проблемы. Что ещё нужно казалось бы? Вот собственно и его код:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <thread>

void ModFunction()
{
    while (true)
    {
    }
}

DWORD WINAPI ThreadProc(LPVOID lpParameter)
{
    ModFunction(); // Вызов функции мода

    return 0;
}

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule, DWORD ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
            // Создаем новый поток для кода мода
            CreateThread(NULL, 0, ThreadProc, NULL, 0, NULL);
            break;

        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
            // Код очистки и завершения работы мода
            break;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

Бесконечный цикл - "индикатор параллельности". Если игра запустилась - значит мод идёт параллельно с игрой. Если она просто встала и не стартует, значит она ждёт конца выполнения бесконечного цикла, чего быть не должно

Comment: В функции `DllMain` нельзя делать почти ничего. Создавать потоки тоже нельзя.

Comment: Тогда есть идеи по решению проблемы выше?

Comment: Создавать поток где-нибудь ещё. Например, в отдельной инициализирующей функции, которая вызывается после загрузки DLL.